# Realm Model Class files

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

I'm new to Realm. Creating a new Model with multiple object classes. Do all class files go into a single Realm Model object? None of the examples show any more than a single class.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Apple Swift 3.0

Comment: Not familiar with Swift myself, but could you explain why you'd want to have multiple classes per file? I don't really think that Realm has anything to do with your question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211359/is-it-acceptable-to-create-multiple-classes-in-one-swift-file-or-should-i-crea

Comment: All Realm DB examples only show a model with a single class. I have an app I'd like to use Realm sync with that has seven Core Data entities.  How do I set this up in Realm. In a single Swift file with all seven or inseven separate Realm Model swift files?

Comment: I really dont think it matters. It's a personal opinion where you place your classes, whether you split them, or combine them. As long as the classes can be referenced in the code where you execute the realm queries, it should work either way

Answer (score 0):

From a compiler or Realm framework perspective it really doesn't matter, you could have all your classes in one file if you'd want to.

On the other hand though, for you (and your team) it really does matter if you write readable, easy to understand and maintain code.

If depends on how large and complex your model is. If you have tens of model classes, grouping them by general purpose or by inheritance could make sense (the base class for a type of object - say the `Vehicle` base class - and all the child classes - the `Car`, `Truck` and `Motorcycle` classes). On the other hand if your model classes are complex, with lots of additional functionality added then having one file per class could be the sensible thing to do.

By the way, if you need to add lots and lots of other code to your model classes (besides the properties you want stored in Realm and the few methods Realm is asking you to override) you may want to **split one class between several files** for clarity and separation of duties (using [class extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html))